# MVC View returns only json formated data using jqGrid

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

Using JQGrid in MVC Showing Json formated text as a View. New to MVC and Razor please help in detail. find my code below.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Reflection;


namespace jGridSample.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetJqGridData(string page, string rows, string sidx, string sord)
    {
        var jqGridData = new JqGridObject()
        {
            Data = GetLoggingDetails(),
            Page = page,
            PageSize = 3, 
            SortColumn = sidx,
            SortOrder = sord
        };
        return Json(jqGridData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public List<GOALogging> GetLoggingDetails()
    {
        string connString = "server=6.15.265.23;database=ACT2_OL_IGP;uid=s_user;pwd=password;Pooling=true;Connection Lifetime=86400;Min Pool Size=50;Max Pool Size=2000";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "GET_SAMPLEDETAILS";
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dataTable);
        conn.Close();
        da.Dispose();

        List<GOALogging> items = new List<GOALogging>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            items.Add(new GOALogging { CRT_DT = Convert.ToDateTime(row["CRT_DT"]), 
                                        PROCESS_FLG = row["PROCESS_FLG"].ToString(),
                                        STATUS_CODE = row["STATUS_CODE"].ToString(),
                                        STATUS_MESSAGE = row["STATUS_MESSAGE"].ToString(),
                                        SERV_TRANS_ID = row["SERV_TRANS_ID"].ToString()
                                        });
        }
        return items;
    }

    public class JqGridObject
    {
        public string Page { get; set; }
        public int PageSize { get; set; }
        public string SortColumn { get; set; }
        public string SortOrder { get; set; }
        public List<GOALogging> Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class GOALogging
    {
        public string SERV_TRANS_ID { get; set; }
        public string STATUS_CODE { get; set; }
        public string STATUS_MESSAGE { get; set; }
        public string PROCESS_FLG { get; set; }
        public DateTime CRT_DT { get; set; }
    }

    }
}
```

View Code:

```
@{
   Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.intellisense.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myGrid").jqGrid({
            url: '/home/GetJqGridData',
            datatype: 'json',
            myType: 'GET',
            colNames: ['SERV_TRANS_ID', 'STATUS_CODE', 'STATUS_MESSAGE', 'PROCESS_FLG', 'CRT_DT'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'SERV_TRANS_ID', index: 'SERV_TRANS_ID' },
            { name: 'STATUS_CODE', index: 'STATUS_CODE' },
            { name: 'STATUS_MESSAGE', index: 'STATUS_MESSAGE' },
            { name: 'PROCESS_FLG', index: 'PROCESS_FLG' },
            { name: 'CRT_DT', index: 'CRT_DT' }
            ],
            pager: $('#myPager'),
            rowNum: 5,
            width: 600,
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'Grid View'
        });
    });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myGrid"></table>

<div id="myPager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And URL i have used is http://localhost:52326/home/GetJqGridData
please find the result i am getting
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Mostly happens because you are calling your JsonResult rather than ActionResult in your controller.

[Reference Example](http://www.fourthbottle.com/2016/02/jqgrid-using-mvc-with-razor-view-engine-in-dotnet.html)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is with **how you construct the JqGridObject** and the signature looks wrong too use int for page and rows.

First of all from the link in  [Here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data)   JqGrid expects its json in the following format you can not send jqgrid any json with out overriding the reader

```
jQuery("#gridid").jqGrid({
...
   jsonReader : { 
      root: "rows", 
      page: "page", 
      total: "total", 
      records: "records", 
      repeatitems: true, 
      cell: "cell", 
      id: "id",
      userdata: "userdata",
      subgrid: { 
         root:"rows", 
         repeatitems: true, 
         cell:"cell" 
      } 
   },
...
});
```

so that means your data should be in the rows field is how I would do it.

Avoid using JqGridObject and use object initializer. You also don't need the SortColumn, SortOrder in there you have to specify those in the client side.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetJqGridData(int page, int rows, string sidx, string sord)
    {

       var data = GetLoggingDetails();

        var jqGridData = new
        {
            total = data.Count,
            rows = GetLoggingDetails(),
            page = page,
            records = rows, 
        };

        return Json(jqGridData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In the client side code
change

```
myType: 'GET' to  mtype: 'GET'
```

FYI: all jqgrid methods are case senstive so be careful.

Other solution is to override the json reader 
and add this to the jqgrid

```
....
mType: 'GET',
jsonReader : { 
          root: "Data", 
          page: "Page"
},
....
```